# No puedo borrar ningun archivo de mi proyecto en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Soy nuevo usando Java y he realizado un par de proyectos en Netbeans. No habia tenido este problema hasta que recién lo instalé y empecé a usar en otro equipo. Lo que me pasa es que intento borrar archivos del proyecto y no sucede nada. Los archivos siguen ahi. Aclaro que lo que quiero es borrarlos de la lista del proyecto, ya que se que aun cuando los borre permanecen en la carpeta donde se almacenan. El siguiente video muestra lo que me está pasando https://www.loom.com/share/ef149d68f9b349b58d4f08082a47cf4d.

Mi sistema operativo es Windows 8 Single Language. Nunca habia tenido probelmas al borrar los archivos en otros SO como Windows 7 y Windows 10. Espero haya sido claro al respecto.

Comment: La forma más sencilla, será en caso de que haya un error en el programa y no te deje eliminar como es el caso, es clik derecho explorar archivo y lo eliminas desde directorios de Windows. Espero que sirva de ayuda.

Comment: No quiere eliminar los archivos del disco, sino sacarlos del proyecto.

Answer (score 3):

Seleciona el archivo y despues darle al suprimir y no marque la casilla si despues sigue saliendo has un f5 y un clean and build proyect eso se encuentra en run/clean and build proyect

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución sin querer. Honestamente desconozco porque y como pero funcionó perfectamente. Lo que tuve que hacer fue borrar el archivo **index.lock** de la carpeta .git. Aqui pueden ver el video de la evidencia [Probelma de borrar archivos Netbeans - Resuelto](https://www.loom.com/share/9c6ae184971c4ec99e743953588ebd08).

En mi caso la carpeta esta en *C:\Users\usuario\.git*. Lo que ahora veo es que me sale un icono pequeño que muestra un tooltip que dice "Contains added, modified or deleted files". Adjunto la imagen.

[image: Iconos nuevos después de borrar index.lock]

En resumen, parece ser un problema con control de versiones de git lo que causaba el problema o algo asi. Tambien soy nuevo usando git y no se como me metí en este embrollo. Pero ya quedó resuelto.